# Return to calling method - BlockingCollection queue items

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, queue

i need some help with ConcurrentQueue's and the BlockingCollection.

The scenario is im trying to throttle requests and conform to a 1 request per second limit, the throttling will occur when i dequeue an item from the queue. The application is a MVC 4 app, so there potentially can be multiple producers at any given time, and there is only one consumer/web service i am contacting.

- Producer `GetUser(string url)` will add a Request to the queue, a
  request is just a url.
- Process the first item in the BlockingCollection by perform some checks to make sure it doesnt violate limits.
- Download a response from the consumer
- Then somehow return the download response to the calling method. ThrottledDownload

In short i would like to process an item in the queue, download the response and send it back to the calling method. Sending it back to the calling method is where im stuck. What options do i have here?

```
//I want to do something like this, and wait for the throttled response to return
public class WebService()
{
    public string GetUser(string name) 
    {
         var url = buildUrl(name);

         var response = string.Empty;

         var downloadTask = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => {
               response = WebServiceHelper.ThrottledDownload(url);
         });
         downloadTask.Wait();
         return response;
    }
}

public static class WebServiceHelper()
{
  private static BlockingCollection<Request> requests = new BlockingCollection<Request>();

  static WebServiceHelper()
  {
       foreach(var item in requests.GetEnumerableConsumer()) {
         string response = DoWork(item.Url);
         //How can i send this back to the calling method?
       }
  }

  public static string ThrottledDownload(string url)
  {
     //Add the request to the blocking queue 
     requests.Add(new Request(url, someId));

     //How do i get the result of the DoWork method?
  } 
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're manually creating workers and not just using the thread pool?  By the sound of it you can just do the work in a call to `Task.Run` in which case you can then use the results of the processing through a `ContinueWith` call on the `Task`.

Comment: @Servy I need to execute the work (Http Request to a web service) sequentially, and conform to the 1 request per second rule. Tbh i havent looked at the ThreadPool as i thought a thread safe queue would be ideal after reading about it. In practice though, im not sure how to return results back to the calling process in a multi producer single consumer scenario

Comment: Please elaborate (edit your question to provide more information) on what "return results" means here. It's unclear to me where requests are coming from and what process or thread you want to notify when work is complete.

Comment: @JimMischel Tried to make my question easier to understand. Basically when processing a queue item i want to return some data back to the ThrottleDownload method.

Comment: It's still unclear. Do you want the `ThrottleDownload` method to block, waiting for a response? Perhaps an explanation of what problem you're trying to solve would give us some more information to go on.

Comment: @JimMischel Updated again. Added my scenario. no the ThrottleDownload method doesnt need to block i imagined doing that when pulling the request from the BlockingCollection queue.

Comment: What was your solution in the end? Did you come up with one?

Comment: @Michael I ended up using semaphores.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to "return a result" to the `ThrottledDown` method. At least, I wouldn't think so. If you did want to do that, you'd have to make some kind of blocking call. Or use a `Task` with continuation ... perhaps `async` in C# 5.

It's still unclear what the main thread is doing. I assume it's queuing a bunch of requests that the consumer thread processes at one-second intervals (presumably to prevent you from being throttled by the server that you're querying). You then want the main thread (or something) to be notified so that it can ... do something.

The flow of your program is still unclear.

Depending on what you want the main thread to do (and what information you want it to do that with), you have a number of options. You can:

- Create another `BlockingCollection` of results. When the consumer completes a request, it adds an object to that collection. The main thread polls that collection to get notification of request completions.
- A variation on the above is to use a pipeline. One thread queues requests. One thread dequeues requests, makes Web requests, and then puts results into another queue. A third thread processes that second queue.
- Add an event (i.e. `ManualResetEventSlim`, for example) to each of your `Request` objects. The consumer calls `Set` on that event when it's completed the request. The main thread either waits on that event, or polls it periodically.
- Have the consumer execute a callback function (defined at compile time, or passed in the `Request` object that you add to the queue). That callback function can notify the main thread, log the result, or whatever you like.

Again, without more information about your application and the higher level problem you're trying to solve, it's rather difficult to make more specific recommendations.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I think i made my answer unclear adding all the extra information where really I simply want to just process an item from the queue and return some data to a waiting method.